# Is it possible to have conditional redirection?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question and I search and I didn't get a clear answer.

I deleted over 1000 pages, and I redirect all to `shop page`, I have a URL like `https://mywebsite.com/shop/` I want to redirect the user to a different category based on the source of the URL.

Example: If users redirected from `https://mywebsite.com/mobile/` to `https://mywebsite.com/shop/` , it automatically redirect the visitor to `https://mywebsite.com/ham/`.

In fact, my question is that is it possible to redirect visitors to 3rd-page base on the first URL?

Comment: Just create a new redirect from https://mywebsite.com/mobile/ to https://mywebsite.com/ham/. Skip the middle redirect.

Comment: No in fact this is an example, I just want to know is it possible to redirect users to 3rd-page based on the first URL?

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei _is it possible_ Yes.

Comment: @nice_dev Thanks, I should use .htaaccess or there is another way?

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei - You can use htaccess itself.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei Via .htaccess, how are you going to give conditions for say, `mobile` -> `ham`? I believe there would be 1000s of them. Better remove the intermediate redirection?